# What does "wishy-washy" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, adjectives, colloquialisms

**Question:** What does it mean when something is "wishy-washy"?
Is it informal? Is it American English, British English or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is informal and idiomatic. It is both BrE and AmE. Though there's no confusion in meaning, the dates of origin differ.

[Wishy-washy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wishy-washy) means lacking in strength of character or purpose; ineffective; lacking in decisiveness; without strength or character; **irresolute**. Synonyms are namby-pamby, spineless, gutless
and weak.

It could also mean thin and watery; pale, bland, wan, pallid, insipid. *She always dresses in wishy-washy pastel colors*.

It originates from *washy* (1560–70) meaning weak, watery, over-diluted: *washy potatoes*, or lacking in strength or vigor; insipid: a weak and *washy* production.
Sometime early on, a reduplication occurred (as in flip-flop, or fuzzy-wuzzy), leading to *wishy-washy*.

[Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wishy-washy) gives its origins as 1690 (in the OED) for the meaning *feeble or poor in quality* (reduplication of washy) and first recorded 1873 in the sense of *vacillating*

> For years people have been allowed to get away with this rather **wishy washy** idea that in the Sixties we smoked cannabis and it didn't matter. But in the Sixties it was a much less powerful drug, and now they have this stuff that is home-grown, which is at least 12 times more powerful." - former British Tory leader Iain Duncan Smith

Comment: It's a _freeze_, as Cooper and Ross call them [in "World Order."](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf)